# How to Solve System of Parametric Equations

Tags: parametric, collision-detection

I am trying to represent two cars approaching an intersection where one car is traveling from a negative point along the x axis and another car is traveling from a negative point up the y-axis.

I have one car whose position is determined by the following:

$$x_1(t) = x_0+v_1*t+1/2*a_1*t^2$$
$$y_1(t) = 0$$

And another car whose position is determined by:

$$x_2(t) = 0$$
$$y_2(t) = y_0+v_2*t+1/2*a_2*t^2$$

How do I tell if there exists a time t for which these two cars collide at the origin with respect to the variables given?

Answer (score 0):

You need to solve the system $$x_1(t)=y_2(t)=0.$$

For convenience, you can form the equation

$$a_2x_1(t)-a_1x_2(t)=0$$ which is linear in $t$.

After finding $t$, plug in the system and check if that $t$ matches.

Comment: I understand why I need to solve the system $$x_1(t)=y_2(t)=0$$ but I do not understand how the second equation is formed or how that is linear in t since $$x_1(t)$$ is non-linear.

Comment: @KyleKauffman: expand the equation and see.

Comment: I expanded out the formula but do not see how it simplifies to the equation you listed for convenience. Because $$a_1x_2(t)$$ is equal to zero since $$x_2(t)=0$$ Doesn't this simplify to $$(x_0-y_0)+t*(v_1-v_2)+1/2*t^2*(a_1-a_2)=0$$ And this is quadratic, not linear. Meaning t either does not exist, or it has up to two solutions.